# Как передать href в ссылку?

Tags: javascript, href

Как передать ссылки из тегов `a` в соответствующие созданные через append новые ссылки?

```js
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
let map = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < heading.length; ++i) {
    let a = heading[i].querySelectorAll("a");
    let groupName = a[0].textContent.trim();
    for (let j = 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
        let companyName = a[j].textContent.trim();
        let href = a[j].href;
        let companyGroups = map.get(companyName);
        if (companyGroups) companyGroups.push({ groupName, href });
        else map.set(companyName, [{ groupName, href }]);
    }
}

let compare = (new Intl.Collator("ru")).compare;
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = "some-style";
let companies = Array.from(map.keys()).sort(compare);
for (let companyName of companies) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = companyName;
    li.append(a);
    
    let li_ul = document.createElement("ul");
    let companyGroups = map.get(companyName).sort(compare);
    for (let groupName of companyGroups) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.textContent = groupName;
        li.append(a);
        li_ul.append(li);
    }
    li.append(li_ul);
    
    ul.append(li);
}

document.querySelector('.input').append(ul);
```

```css
.some-style {
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input"><div>
<ul class="hide">
  <li class="heading"><a href="google.com/samsung">Телевизоры</a>   
     <ul>
       <li><a href="google.com/samsung" href="google.com/samsung">Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a href="google.com/samsung" href="google.com/samsung">Lenovo</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="heading"><a href="google.com/samsung">Планшеты</a>   
     <ul>
       <li><a href="google.com/lenovo-03">Lenovo</a></li>
       <li><a href="google.com/samsung">Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a href="google.com/acer-43">Acer</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="heading"><a>Ноутбуки</a>     
     <ul>
       <li><a href="google.com/lenovo-83">Lenovo</a></li>
       <li><a href="google.com/samsung-323">Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a href="google.com/acer-021">Acer</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А это `a.href = ...` разве не помогает?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg ноуп, что-то делаю не так..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
let map = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < heading.length; ++i) {
  let a = heading[i].querySelectorAll("a");
  let groupName = a[0].textContent.trim();
  for (let j = 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
    let companyName = a[j].textContent.trim();
    let href = a[j].href;
    let companyGroups = map.get(companyName);
    if (companyGroups) companyGroups.push({
      groupName,
      href
    });
    else map.set(companyName, [{
      groupName,
      href
    }]);
  }
}

let compare = (new Intl.Collator("ru")).compare;
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = "some-style";
let companies = Array.from(map.keys()).sort(compare);
for (let companyName of companies) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.textContent = companyName;
  li.append(a);

  let li_ul = document.createElement("ul");
  let companyGroups = map.get(companyName).sort(compare);
  for (let group of companyGroups) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = group.href;
    a.textContent = group.groupName;
    li.append(a);
    li_ul.append(li);
  }
  li.append(li_ul);
  ul.append(li);
}

document.querySelector('.input').append(ul);
```

```css
.some-style {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <div>
    <ul class="hide">
      <li class="heading"><a href="google.com/samsung">Телевизоры</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com/samsung" href="google.com/samsung">Samsung</a></li>
          <li><a href="google.com/samsung" href="google.com/samsung">Lenovo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="heading"><a href="google.com/samsung">Планшеты</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com/lenovo-03">Lenovo</a></li>
          <li><a href="google.com/samsung">Samsung</a></li>
          <li><a href="google.com/acer-43">Acer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="heading"><a>Ноутбуки</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com/lenovo-83">Lenovo</a></li>
          <li><a href="google.com/samsung-323">Samsung</a></li>
          <li><a href="google.com/acer-021">Acer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```